# Fast way to create dict of dicts and insert element in python?

Tags: python, dictionary

Is there a way to condense this code?

```
    key2 = 1
    self.mydict = {1:{}}
    if key1 in self.mydict.keys():
        self.mydict[key1][key2] = None
    else:
        self.mydict[key1] = {}
        self.mydict[key1][key2] = None
```

As you can see if the key doesn't exist I need to first initialize the dict inside the dict. Can I create a nested dict and insert an element into the nested dict automatically regardless of whether the inner dict exists or not?

Comment: check out `collections.defaultdict()` and/or `setdefault()`

Comment: What is the value of key1? It would help to clarify your objective if key1 and key2 were different values and you show the required output. But as @JonSG says, setdefault is almost certainly the way to go

Answer (score 0):

Would this suite your needs?  It uses `setdefault()` though others may find `collections.defaultdict()` to be easier to use.

```py
key1 = 1
key2 = 2
mydict = {}
mydict.setdefault(key1, {}).setdefault(key2, None)
print(mydict)
```

That should give you:

```
1: {2: None}}
```

which is what I think you are seeking.